# Loop through a string array to match a pattern

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0

I have a log file that I'm trying to parse with Regex.

I create an array of rows from the log file like this:

```
let loadLog =
    File.ReadAllLines "c:/access.log"
        |> Seq.filter (fun l -> not (l.StartsWith("#")))
        |> Seq.map (fun s -> s.Split()) 
        |> Seq.map (fun l -> l.[7],1)
        |> Seq.toArray
```

I then need to loop through this array.  But I don't think this will work because line needs to be a string.

Is there a special way to handle something like this in f#?

```
type ActorDetails =
    {
        Date: DateTime
        Name: string
        Email: string
    }

for line in loadLog do
    let line queryString  =
        match queryString  with
        | Regex @"[\?|&]system=([^&]+)" [json] ->
             let jsonValue = JValue.Parse(Uri.UnescapeDataString(json))
             {
                  Date = DateTime.UtcNow (* replace with parsed date *)
                  Name = jsonValue.Value<JArray>("name").[0].Value<string>()
                  Email = jsonValue.Value<JArray>("mbox").[0].Value<string>().[7..]
             }
```

Comment: What do you want to do inside the loop? As it stands, your `let line queryString` would be defining a function - which I suspect is not what you want to do...

Comment: @TomasPetricek Yeah I added code to make it more clear.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Partial Active Pattern (|Regex|_|) to do that

```
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let (|Regex|_|) regexPattern input =
    let regex = new Regex(regexPattern)
    let regexMatch = regex.Match(input)
    if regexMatch.Success 
    then Some regexMatch.Value
    else None

let queryString input = function
    | Regex  @"[\?|&]system=([^&]+)" s -> s
    | _ -> sprintf "other: %s" input
```